# Counting unique text values in range using Match and Row functions in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, function

I need to count unique text values in a range. I'm trying to recreate the following formula in VBA **=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(MATCH(B2:B197,B2:B197,0),ROW(B2:B197)-ROW(B2)+1)>0))**. I tried rewriting the formula above using VBA code

```
Dim NumLabels As Variant
NumLabels = SumProduct(--Frequency(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range(Cells(2,2),Cells(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count,2)),Range(Cells(2,2),Cells(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count,2)),0),
```

This is as far as I was able to get. I don't know how to use the function **=ROW()** in VBA.

Or is there a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Show us all of the code you're using for this please :)

Comment: @DZZ: Welcome to Stack Overflow: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question and be sure to ask a [good, clear, concise question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion),  include the code, expected behaviour, and what is wrong... then we can try to help

Comment: @DZZ: for example, what specific issues are you having with `ROW` and `MATCH` - wrong value, doesn't compile, error's out, Excel crashes, Windows crashes, desk catches fire? see [F8 Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) and [Ozgrid: Debugging Excel VBA](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/debug.htm) and [Eric Lippert: How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/)

Comment: @OurManinBananas updated. My main issue is that I'm not familiar on how to use the functions in Excel in VBA so I am stuck here.

Comment: @DZZ: in VBA, the syntax is `vRow = Range("A1").row` so in your case (based **solely on your sample code**) it might be something like `Range("B2:B197").Row - Range("B2").Row + 1`